# Convert multiple columns html table to a single column for Mobile friendly layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a table with 3 columns. I would like to convert to single row.

[image]

```
both append.('</tr><tr>') and after.('</tr><tr>') do not work.
```

Want it like this for mobile friendly page -

[image]

Thank you for your help!

http://jsfiddle.net/tZt3Q/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way you can achieve this is by using JQuery wrap method. See <kbd>[Wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)</kbd>  and  <kbd>[UnWrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)</kbd>

<kbd>***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z3r9b/)***</kbd>

<kbd>***[Demo W/O class](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z9h9/)***</kbd>

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var tbl = $("table");
      $('td','table').unwrap().each(
     function () {     
          tbl.append($(this).wrap('<tr>').parent()); 
    });
  });
```

Much simpler one:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('table').find('td').unwrap().wrap($('<tr/>'));
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bs7Rg/)**

Comment: I learn something new everyday here at SO.  Elegant solution PScoder.

Comment: @PSCoder I tested it. It unwraps **table** tag too. Now the result is like `..<body><tr><td>...`

Comment: @PSCoder +1 Your edited code works. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Single Row**:

```
var $tds = $("table td").clone();
$("table").empty().append($("<tr>").append($tds));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/tZt3Q/10/

**Single Column**:

```
var $tds = $("table td").clone();
$("table").empty();
$tds.each(function(){
    $("table").append($("<tr>").append($(this)));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/tZt3Q/11/

Comment: It is an opposite of what I want. I would like to have rows with one cell only instead of all cells in a single row.

Comment: Got confused cause you say "I would like to convert to single row" in your question. Maybe it is clear in the images but I can't see the images :p (blocked domain at work)

Comment: +1 Your edited code works. I cannot accept both answer. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a suggestion .. you could use `divs` as cells  instead of a table and it will happen without any JS using float css:

like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/tZt3Q/9/

HTML:

```
<div class="tableDivColumns">
<div>One</div><div>Tow</div><div>Three</div><div>Four</div><div>Five</div><div>six</div>
    <div>Seven</div><div>Eight</div><div>Nine</div>
</div>

<div class="tableDivRows">
<div>One</div><div>Tow</div><div>Three</div><div>Four</div><div>Five</div><div>six</div>
    <div>Seven</div><div>Eight</div><div>Nine</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tableDivColumns {border:1px solid green; padding 5px; width:160px;height:160px;}
.tableDivColumns div {border:1px solid blue; width:50px; height:50px;float:left;}

.tableDivRows {border:1px solid green; padding 5px; width:60px;height:470px;}
.tableDivRows div {border:1px solid blue; width:50px; height:50px;float:left;}
```

Comment: It is a legacy ASP.Net control, so I cannot convert to div tag easily without spending a lot of time. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Understood, keep in mind that the JS might be a performance hit depending on the amount of cells so i would check it out before if its relevant.